# Unable to get Struts2 Hello World to work using Eclipse and Maven

Tags: java, jsp, struts2, xml-configuration, action-mapping

This site doesn't allow user to ask technical questions to their tutorial which I believe is broken:

http://www.mkyong.com/misc/how-to-use-mkyong-tutorial/

I'm using:

- maven: 3.2.1
- tomcat 7
- java 1.7
- Eclipse: Luna Release (4.4.0)

I'm getting this message:

```
WARNING: Could not find action or result
There is no Action mapped for namespace [/] and action name [] associated with context path [/Struts2Example]. - [unknown location]
```

I can never get to the `login.jsp` page unless I enter the full url.  But even then, when I click on the submit button, it doesn't go to the `welcome_user.jsp` page either.

Can someone tell me how I can fix this and get this Hello World example to work in using Eclipse?

Comment: So find a better tutorial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you follow the tutorial, which is linked to the page [Struts 2 Hello World Example](https://www.mkyong.com/struts2/struts-2-hello-world-example/), and done everything till p. 7 then you should **Run it** as is written

> In Struts2, you can access the action class directly with a suffix of
> .action.
>
> `http://localhost:8080/Struts2Example/User/Login.action`

If you tried to access application as

```
http://localhost:8080/Struts2Example
```

you will get a message and 404 error code is returned to the browser.

> WARNING: Could not find action or result There is no Action mapped for
> namespace [/] and action name [] associated with context path
> [/Struts2Example]. - [unknown location]

The workaround is to add the file to the web root folder that will redirect a browser to the correct location.

**`index.html`:**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
<html>
<head>
    <META HTTP-EQUIV="Refresh" CONTENT="0;URL=User/Login.action">
</head>

<body>
<p>Loading ...</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Also modify web application deployment descriptor to include this file name to the welcome files list.

**`web.xml`:**

```
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

That's it, if you are looking for the Hello World tutorial, you should use these references:

- [Hello World](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/plugins/servlet/mobile?contentId=13924#content/view/13924)
- [Hello World Using Struts 2](https://struts.apache.org/getting-started/hello-world-using-struts2.html)
- [How To Create A Struts 2 Web Application](https://struts.apache.org/getting-started/how-to-create-a-struts2-web-application.html)
- 

[Create Struts 2 Web Application Using Maven To Manage Artifacts and To Build The Application](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/plugins/servlet/mobile?contentId=14811868#content/view/14811868)