# Trying Struts 2 for the first time and getting 404 Not Found Error. How would I solve this?

Tags: java, struts2

I am new to struts and little confused about project in regards of Web apps. I am practicing simple struts project with following:

struts.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.0//EN" "http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.0.dtd">

<struts>
    <constant name="struts.devMode" value="true" />

    <package name="helloworld" extends="struts-default">

        <action name="sayhello" class="com.demo.action.HelloAction">
            <result name="success">/hello.jsp</result>
            <result name="error">/error.jsp</result>
        </action>

    </package>
</struts>
```

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<WebContent>
    <filter>
        <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
        <filter-class>
            org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.FilterDispatcher
        </filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
</WebContent>
```

HelloAction.java

```
package com.demo.action;

import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionSupport;

public class HelloAction extends ActionSupport{

    public String execute() {

        return SUCCESS;
    }

}
```

And this is my project structure:
[image: hello-struts]

My error:
[image: 404 Not Found Error]

Comment: web.xml should start with a `<web-app>` tag and a closing `</web-app>` not <WebContent>

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/25378721/573032